# Remove Splash Screen on Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, splash-screen

is possible to remove the default Splash Screen on Windows Phone 8.1? For app I'm develoving, I don't need the Splash Screen.

Thanks

Comment: Default splash screen? When the phone starts up? In a specific project template? Wha...?

Answer (score 3):

If you open the Visual Assets tab you can change `Assets\SplashScreen.png` to whatever you want.

I'm not sure if this can just be removed though but if not, I suppose you could change it to a screenshot of your app if you want to fake the behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made as you told, I used a fake background screen for Splash Screen. 
I hoped that implementing an Extended Splash Screen was the solution, but I don't know how to set the time for Splash (like 0 milliseconds).

Answer (score 0):

In extended SplashScreen page in OnNavigatedTo method start a dispatchTimer and set timer to time which you require and then do as you wish.

```
Loader.IsActive=true;
            DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000) };
            _timer.Start();
            _timer.Tick+=_timer_Tick;
```